# Adobe cs5 actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm doing a simple drag and drop  number game for kids. Once the user places all the numbers and presses the go button (btn_go)  how do I get a another button appearing after the user has click the go button?

Answer (score 0):

I think you ask about "How get DisplayObject by name in Flash, from main stage?"?
If I'm rigth

```
stage.getChildByName("nameOfMyAnotherBtn");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn_go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnGoClicked);

function btnGoClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    another_button.visible = true;
    btn_go.visible = false; //Optionally hide button go
}
```

Likewise, if you wanted to show/hide btn_go when another_button is clicked it's the same idea.